# Ponto inicial do eixo X utilizando scale_x_date()

Tags: r, ggplot2, chart

Estou fazendo um gráfico de área empilhada e utilizo o seguinte código

```
ggplot(gdados, aes(Commissioned, acum, fill = Country)) +
  geom_area(col=c('black')) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")+
  scale_x_date(breaks= "10 years", labels = date_format("%Y"), limits = c(as.Date('1920-01-01'),as.Date('2020-01-01')))+
  labs(x = "Ano", y = 'Potência Instalada [MW]', fill = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,160000,10000)) +  
  theme_minimal()
```

A referência no eixo x começa a ser mostrada a partir do ano de 1924 e termina no ano 2024, com quebras de 10 em 10 anos. Como faço para começar no ano 1920 e, com as quebras de 10 em 10 anos, terminar em 2020 a ultima quebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, vamos criar os dados que serão usados para reproduzir o problema e depois para demonstrar a solução.

```
set.seed(123)
dados <- data.frame(data = seq(Sys.Date(), by = "-1 year", length.out = 100),
           val = rnorm(100, 100, 15))
```

Com esse objeto `dados`, podemos criar um gráfico com problemas similares com o código abaixo:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dados, aes(data, val)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", breaks = "10 years")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como se nota na imagem, ocorre o problema em que, apesar de 10 anos de invervalo entre um *tick*  e outro, eles não estão nos multiplus de 10 (1930, 1940, etc...).

Para resolver isso podemos indicar aquelas datas que devem aparecer nos *ticks* com o argumento `breaks`. Podemos criar essas datas com a função `seq`(me modo similar ao feito para criar os dados). Assim teríamos

```
ggplot(dados, aes(data, val)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y",
               breaks = seq(as.Date("1920-01-01"), by = "10 years", length.out = 11))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Importante ressaltar que ao criarmos essa sequência de datas indicamos:

1. Em que data ela começava (janeiro de 1920)
2. O tamanho dos "pulos" entre uma data e outra (10 anos)
3. Qual o tamanho que a sequência deveria ter (11 elementos)

Há outras formas de criar essas sequências, seja incluindo um objeto que a sequência deve acompanhar (ou seja ter o mesmo tamanho), argumento `along.with`, ou então indicar a data em que a sequência deve terminar, argumento `to`.

Comment: Resolvido e entendido. Muito Obrigado!